# $K = \frac{2013^2}{2011 \times 2012} - \frac{2011^2}{2012 \times 2013}\;\;\; $. Then $\lfloor K \rfloor = $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\displaystyle K = \frac{2013^2}{2011 \times 2012} - \frac{2011^2}{2012 \times 2013}\;\;\; $. Then $\lfloor K \rfloor = $

My try:: Let $\displaystyle K = \frac{2013^3-2011^3}{2011 \times 2012 \times 2013}$

Now Let $x = 2012$, Then $x+1 = 2013$ and $x-1 = 2011$

So $\displaystyle K = \frac{(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3}{(x-1).x.(x+1)} = \frac{2x.\left\{(x+1)^2+(x-1)^2+x^2-1\right\}}{x.(x^2-1)}$

So $\displaystyle K = 2.\left(\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right) = 2.\left(\frac{3x^2-3+4}{x^2-1}\right)=6+\frac{8}{x^2-1}$

So $\displaystyle 6<K<7$.

So $\lfloor K \rfloor = 6$

Is My process is Right or not,

plz check my solution,

Thanks

Comment: Actually [$\lfloor K\rfloor = 0$](https://www.google.com/search?q=2013^2%2F%282011*2012%29+-+2011^2%2F%282012*2013%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a decimal < 1, so the floor function of it would be 0, I am assuming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process, or rather a step that you made in it, is incorrect. Note that

$$(x+1)^3 - (x-1)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1 - (x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1) = 6x^2 + 2.$$

Therefore

$$\dfrac{(x+1)^3 - (x-1)^3}{(x-1)x(x+1)} = \dfrac{6x^2 + 2}{x(x^2 - 1)} = -\frac{2}{x} + \frac{4}{x-1} + \frac{4}{x+1}.$$

Now note that $\dfrac{4}{x-1} - \dfrac{2}{x} > 0$ for $x > 1$, so $\lfloor K\rfloor \geq 0$. For $x > 9$, both $\dfrac{4}{x - 1}$ and $\dfrac{4}{x+1}$ are less than $\dfrac{1}{2}$ so $\lfloor K \rfloor < 1$. Therefore $\lfloor K\rfloor = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Michael Albanese....